# Laravel cashier using stripe success route and cancel says login not defined

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am creating a REST api using laravel (sanctum) and I integrated cashier/stripe package. When I do a subscription, I want the user to redirect to stripe page and setup the payment method there and select the plan based on my project.

Here is what in my function

```
    public function createSubscription()
    {
        if(PaymentBillingMethod::byName($this->data['billing_method'])->value === PaymentBillingMethod::Monthly->value){
            $subscription = $this->user->newSubscription($this->getSelectedPlanName(), $this->getSelectedPlanStripeID());
            $checkoutSession = $subscription->checkout([
                'success_url' => route('checkout.success'),
                'cancel_url' => route('checkout.cancelled'),
            ]);
            return $checkoutSession->url;
            //return redirect()->away($checkoutSession->url);
        } else {
            $subscription = $this->user->newSubscription($this->getSelectedPlanName(), $this->getSelectedPlanStripeID());
            $checkoutSession = $subscription->checkout([
                'success_url' => route('checkout.success'),
                'cancel_url' => route('checkout.cancelled'),
            ]);
            return $checkoutSession->url;
            //return redirect()->away($checkoutSession->url);
        }
    }
```

Basically when I am using postman it only returns a unique stripe URL which I will redirect/visit and setup a payment method then subscribe to the selected plan.

But when I try to go back (cancel) or to subscribe the selected plan it says `route [login] not defined` though I can successfully subscribe to the selected plan.

[image]

Here is my routes.

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/profile/subscription/checkout-cancel', function () {
            return response()->ok(null, __('Action cancelled'));
        })->name('checkout.cancelled');

        Route::get('/profile/subscription/checkout-success', function () {
            return response()->ok(null, __('Subscription success'));
        })->name('checkout.success');
}
```

Is it possible to pass a token in the success and cancel url so when I came back I am still authenticated?

Comment: The cancel and success url's are meant to be webpages. It looks like you're just returning a string response? In any case, you could just not put those routes behind authentication. If you need to display info on those pages that require the customer to be logged in, then you need to persist login somehow (cookie for example).

Comment: Okay I see. Got it!